# What does the option -m mean in python?

Tags: python, virtualenv

What does the `-m` mean while creating a virtual environment?

For example, `py -3 -m venv env`.

What does the `-m` mean? What's the difference of `venv` and `virtualenv`?

Thanks.

Comment: `-m` *in Python* (i.e. the `python` executable) probably means something very different than `-m` in whatever command it is you're executing there. What exactly is `py`?

Answer (score 4):

> What does the -m mean?

From python manual page:

> -m module-name
>   Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as a script.

`py -m venv env` will tell Python (the Windows version uses `py`) to use execute the [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module and create a virtual environment that will be stored in the `env` directory.

From [virtualenv documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#usage):

> Virtualenv has one basic command:
>
> `$ virtualenv ENV`
>
> Where `ENV` is a directory to place the new virtual environment.

---

> What's the difference of venv and virtualenv?

**venv** and **virtualenv** are just shorter versions of **virtual environment**, meaning that **venv** is the same as **virtualenv** -- there is no difference.